# Spatial Index warning from Spatial Query

Tags: qgis, spatial-index, spatial-query

I'm trying a spatial query using QGIS version 3.10 using a buffer layer and a set of species records. I wish to know how many species records fall within the buffer. When I perform the spatial query by going to Vector>Research Tools>Select by Location and fill in the input layer as species records, type as intersect and comparing features to buffer layer I get the following warning: 'no spatial index for input layer, performance will be severely degraded'.

I've added a spatial index to the layer and still get the same warning occurs.

Does anyone know what causes the initial warning?

Interestingly when I try on another laptop of the same spec with the same layers it works fine.

Is there something in the settings that could resolve this issue?

Comment: which layer did you add the index to?

Comment: I added it to the species record layer. This was the one that was highlighted as not having a spatial index.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Three months into 2021 and still no answer. I am going through the training manual, and at 6.2.10

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html

I tried to extract a layer of "houses_near_restaurants" from a layer of "well_located_buildings". The result looks OK, but I got the same warning of a degraded result, so it made me wonder if the result really is OK and what can be done?

iMac, Catalina